# CMake and VS 2017 : could not find any instance of Visual Studio

Tags: c++, cmake, visual-studio-2017

Running `cmake -G"Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64" ../`

Error:

```
  Generator

    Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64

  could not find any instance of Visual Studio.
```

The file: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\Microsoft.VCToolsVersion.default.txt` is present.

"Desktop development with C++" is installed. My PC has been restarted.

Visual C++ tools for CMake checked / installed.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vswhere.exe"
Visual Studio Locator version 2.7.1+180c706d56
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Are you running those commands from the Visual Studio Command Prompt? If not, are you sure Visual Studio C++ tools are completely installed? And the VC++ compiler is in your environment `Path`?

Comment: Im running from CMD. Yes I'm sure c++ tools are installed as I posted. Not sure about "VC++ compiler is in your environment" thing. Tell me more about it.

Comment: Maybe just generator name is incorrect? it seems it should be `-G "Visual Studio 15 2017" -A x64"`

Comment: Same error with `-G "Visual Studio 15 2017" -A "x64"`

Comment: There is an article about MS Visual Studio installation and environment settings [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/finding-the-visual-c-compiler-tools-in-visual-studio-2017/) which could be helpful. But this can easily be resolved by running from the Developer Command Prompt for Visual Studio.

Comment: Running from the Developer Command Prompt for Visual Studio?

Comment: So I opened that Command Prompt. Whats next?

Comment: Yes, if you have Visual Studio installed you can access the Developer Command prompt from the Start Menu, or from within Visual Studio (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/developer-command-prompt-for-vs#start-the-command-prompt-from-inside-visual-studio)). Then, just type your commands... `cmake -G"Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64" ../`

Comment: Same error :(((